# extremely slow leaflet website - using grunt and topojson files

Tags: performance, gruntjs, leaflet, topojson

I am building a leaflet map of Taiwan census data but it is extremely slow to load. I am already using grunt, and my main data files are all in topojson format and very light. Is there something obvious that makes this slow? Or is it just because there are many layers to load? Here is a [link](http://140.112.64.66/website/taiwancensus/).

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know but for me this website is not **slow**. What is *slow* for you, explain it a little bit =)

Comment: over 15sec to fully load? I am trying to use gzip now on the topojson files..

Comment: Now I see, indeed like 20 seconds. But it's now the issue of downloading the files. It's more the processing. So gzip even make it much more worse! Wouldn't do that. First of all try to reduce loadings at the very start. You seem to do different stuff that is not needed on the first look like the regions I would say.

Comment: How should I reduce loading at the very start? I was thinking maybe have only the topojson load when they are used by the map (when a layer is turned on by a user)?